# Как сделать выход за пределы switch для продолжения работы в консоли?

Tags: c, c++, visual-studio

Добрый вечер!
Имеется структура главной функции:

while (1)
     {

```
 //менюшка1;

        switch (1)
        {
           while()

           {//менюшка2;

               switch (2)
                {}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, с вопросом! Как организовать выход из менюшки 2 в менюшку 1,( т е на уровень выше).
Пробовала через exit(0) и return (-1); Но они выбрасывают из консоли((

Comment: точнее выход нужен все таки из while, но как один из case'ов switch'а.

Comment: break не помогает?

Comment: неа, он выводит на вторую менюшку!даже пробовала через значение во втором while() , которое в case  для выхода обнуляется, все равно выше второй менюшки не выходит.

Comment: А что значит "выход из вайл, но как один из кейсов"? Я похоже до конца не понимаю куда надо "выйти".

Comment: break внутри вайл должен прервать цикл, но данный оператор должен быть именно внутри цикла, а не внутри вложенного кейса, который будет обеспечивать выход из кейса непосредственно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (1) {
 //менюшка1;

        switch (go) 
        { 
 bool go = true;
           while(go)

           {//менюшка2;

               switch (2) 
                {
    go = false;
    continue;

}
```

Comment: Не понял, что это такое. Как это Вы используете переменную go в первом switch еще до ее объявления? И это только одно из замечаний.

Comment: опечатка очевидная. валяйте следующее замечание

Answer (score 4):

Я бы воспользовался `goto`, но многие преподаватели видя его ...
да использовать его надо в крайних случаях...

*добавлено через день:*

Что касается `longjmp`, то я думаю, он будет лишний (преподавателю ещё придётся объяснять что и зачем) но для своего развития полезна:
[Функция longjmp](http://lord-n.narod.ru/download/books/walla/programming/Spr_po_C/18/longjmp.htm).

А `goto` вот:

```
goto имя-метки;
    //...              
имя-метки: оператор;
```

И учти, если у тебя много переходов (`goto`), значит ты что-то не так сделал, лично я использую его только для выхода из большого количества вложенных циклов, когда другого пути нету.

Comment: я тоже уже думала про него, но ни разу не пользовалась и не знаю даже как его направить в начало первого вайла?перед менюшкой1?

Comment: Есть и замены goto (напр. longjmp). В c++ есть механизм исключений. Можно добавить переменную, содержащую признак продолжения цикла while() и сбрасывать её в ветке switch

Comment: longjmp() в данном контексте попахивает безумием (да и исключение тоже).

Comment: @avp насчёт longjmp -- согласен. Насчёт исключений -- нет. Вполне подходящий механизм. Возможно наиболее подходящий, поскольку goto всё-таки некошерно (да если перейти от C/C++ к другим языкам, например той же java, то где будет этот goto?). А синхронные исключительные ситуации (ежели склероз не изменяет) были уже в PL/I, а это середина 60х...

Comment: @alexlz, IMHO исключение это и есть *исключение*, т.е. прерывание *нормального, естественного* течения алгоритма (переполнение массива, некорректные аргументы и т.п.). А программировать нормальный выход из меню на уровень выше через исключения - это идеологически неправильно и PL/I тут ни при чем.


Правильно было бы сделать обработку каждого меню в своей функции, точнее в своей активации общей (одной и той же для всех меню), управляемой описанием конкретного меню функции.

Надеюсь, со временем автор дорастет до этого, а пока goto c флагами.
(break и continue это просто замаскированные goto).

Comment: @avp налицо мировоззренческие разногласия. Увы, мы друг друга не убедим. Но обоснование "идеологически неправильно" мне понравилось. "Религия -- rulez"?

(а break & continue от goto отличаются фиксированной точкой передачи управления)

Comment: @alexlz, вообще-то я не догматик ("идеологически неправильно" просто к слову здесь пришлось) и приемлю любой код (даже goto по void \*), но при условии, что он *красивый*.

Про break&continue правильней было бы сказать не *замаскированный* а *ограниченный* goto, но подредактировать комментарий уже не могу...

Comment: @avp, кстати, при помощи исключений можно было бы здесь написать очень эффектный и эффективный код.

Comment: @mikillskegg, наверное да, но это все равно меню, зашитое в код. Некрасиво.

Answer (score 3):

Я не понял из этого непонятного и некорректного кода, откуда конкретно нужно выйти? Попробуй то место, откуда нужно выйти, обернуть в отдельную функцию, и уже из неё можно будет выходить return'ом без всяких временных переменных и goto.